# How to compare two arrays and see if they have anything in common(PHP)

Tags: php

I need to compare two arrays and pass variable values according to the result.
I loop $additionalTestsAvailable, if $additionalTestsSelected has a value in $additionalTestsSelected, passing 'Yes' to additionalTestsSelected, else passing ''. But the result are all ''. It shouldn't like this. Anything wrong with my code?

```
$additionalTestsSelected = $appointmentTime->getAdditionalTestsSelected();
$additionalTestsAvailable = $appointmentTime->getAdditionalTestsAvailable();

foreach($additionalTestsAvailable as $test) {

    if(in_array($test,$additionalTestsSelected)){
      $additionalTests[$test->getName()] = 'Yes';
    }else{
      $additionalTests[$test->getName()] = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your tests are coming out of the get functions as different objects even when they have the same name so the `in_array` comparison is failing. You can workaround this by looping manually and comparing the tests using their names:

```
foreach ($additionalTestsAvailable as $test) {
    $result = '';
    foreach ($additionalTestsSelected as $k) {
        if ($test->getName() == $k->getName()) {
            $result = 'Yes';
            break;
        }
    }
    $additionalTests[$test->getName()] = $result;
}
```